# How does Vector map() work in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm unable to get the map() function to work at all with a Vector class.

The result always comes back null - it should return me a new vector with the values returned by the addFive function (this example is obviously not my real usecase).

The array version works as expected.

Has anyone had any luck getting map() to work with Vector?

```
    public function test_vector_map():void {
        var v1:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[1,2,3];
        trace(v1); // traces 1,2,3

        var v2:Vector.<uint> = v1.map(addFive);
        trace(v2); // traces null
    }             

    protected function addFive(item:uint, index:int, vector:Vector.<uint>):uint
    {
        return item+5;
    } 

    public function test_array_map():void {
        var v1:Array = [1,2,3];
        trace(v1); // traces 1,2,3
        var v2:Array = v1.map(addSix);
        trace(v2); // traces 7,8,9
    }             

    protected function addSix(item:uint, index:int, array:Array):uint
    {
        return item+6;
    }
```

Comment: Confirmed: The v1 Vector is not changed by the map() function.

Comment: Confirmed: Passing either v1 or the test class itself as the 'this' object (second optional parameter for use where there's a this reference in the function) makes no difference.

Comment: Confirmed: Making the addFive function local to the code that runs the map also doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Confirmed: I originally hit this with a type other than uint, so I don't think it's specific to the uint type.

Comment: Tried messing with this for a while myself. Very odd that the map function fails out and returns null without any error message. Very likely a flex/as3 bug. Might be stuck using arrays for now

Comment: Great, more excellent work from Adobe!  Glad I found this thread before banging my head trying to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an actionscript/flash player bug. It seems adobe has fixed it internally but as of Flash Player 10.1 the fix has not been released.

See:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=513095

which is the root cause of our bug found here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507501

Best thing you can do for now is stick with using Arrays when Map is needed

Comment: Thanks for finding that for me - at least I'm not going insane.

Answer (score 3):

Weird... I am seeing your confirmations. You could always go with this solution:

```
var v1:Vector.<uint> = new <uint>[1,2,3];
trace(v1); // traces 1,2,3

var v2:Vector.<uint> = v1.slice();
v2.forEach( addFive );
trace(v2); // traces 6,7,8
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to make more use of the seemingly useful map/filter etc functions - I usually use a for(var i... ) loop for these things (faster than a forEach) so I'll go back to long hand. Cheers for confirming it for me.